# PHPUnit "with" matcher with array and $this->anything()

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I've got a unit test testing a `PDOStatement::execute()` call with `date()` as one of the array elements.

Something like:

```
$stmt->execute(array ('value1', 'value2', date('Ymd'));
```

The issue is my assertion is using `$this->anything()` to represent that date function result.  I think it's breaking because it's in an array.  Is there a good way to handle this?

My assertion looks like:

```
$mock->expects($this->once())
  ->method('execute')
  ->with(array ('value1', 'value2', $this->anything()));
```

Comment: What does '$this->anything()' return? Couldn't you use date('Y-m-d', time()) ?

Comment: `$this->anything()` usually means something like "I don't care what this parameter is."  I could probably get away with using date() most of the time, except for when the mock is created on that split second before the actual method is tested.

Comment: You may not care what the parameter is, but the SQL statement probably will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't pass argument verification methods to `with()` inside an array. PHPUnit would need to iterate the array and detect the methods. Instead, one of these methods is passed to the `with()` method for each argument the method should receive.

In your case the method will receive a single argument, so you will employ a single verification. You can't employ a generic verification so you'll need to check the array internals using a callback:

```
$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('execute')
     ->with($this->callback(function($array) {
            return 'value1' == $array[0] && 'value2' == $array[1] && 3 == count($array);
        }));
```

This is explained in the [PHPUnit docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html).